# Error creating React components with map() without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Step 1",
    "summary": "",
    "required": true,
    "articles": [
      {
        "name": "Article 1",
        "url": "...",
        "comments": [],
        "questions": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Step 2",
    "required": true,
    "summary": "",
    "articles": [
      {
        "name": "Article 1",
        "url": "...",
        "comments": [],
        "questions": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Step 3",
    "required": false,
    "summary": "",
    "articles": [
      {
        "name": "Article 1",
        "url": "...",
        "comments": [],
        "questions": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Article 2",
        "url": "...",
        "comments": [],
        "questions": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Article 3",
        "url": "...",
        "comments": [],
        "questions": []
      },
      {
        "name": "Article 4",
        "url": "...",
        "comments": [],
        "questions": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Step 4",
    "summary": "Coming Soon!",
    "required": true
  }
]
```

There are Steps and each step can have multiple articles.

Folllowing is the Steps component:

```
import { createElement as ce, Component } from 'react';

class Steps extends Component {

  render() {
    const { steps } = this.props;
    return ce('div', { className:'allTheSteps' }, Step({ steps }));
  };

};

const Step = ({ steps }) => (
  steps.map( ( { name, id, articles }, i ) => ce('div', {className: 'mainBoxes clearfix', key: id},
  ce('strong', {className: 'titleText', key: id + '-' + i}, name),
  ce('div', { className: 'stepArticle'},
    articles.map( ({ name, url }), j ) => Article({ name, url }),
  )
))
);

export default Steps;
```

Following is the Article component:

```
import { createElement as ce } from 'react';

const Article = ({ name, url }) => (
    ce('div', {className: 'articleTitle'},
      ce('input', {type: 'checkbox', name: 'done', className: 'checkBoxes'}),
      ce('a', { className: 'checkLink', target: '_blank', href: url }, name),
      ),
    ce('div', {className: 'articleActions'},
      ce('input', {type: 'button', value: 'Make Notes', className: 'addNotes'}),
      ce('input', {type: 'button', value: 'Ask Clausehound', className: 'askQuestions'}),
      ),
    ce('textarea', {className: 'textAreas notes', placeholder: 'My Notes: '}),
    ce('textarea', {
      className: 'textAreas questions',
      placeholder: 'Questions for Clausehound Research Team: ',
    })
);

export default Article;
```

Following is the index.js which creates the root element:

```
  const steps = await loadSteps(ID); // fetch
  render(
    ce(Steps, { steps },
      ce(Article, steps.articles)
    ),
    document.querySelector('.root'),
  );
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Steps.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

I want to render all the Steps and then the articles within those steps. But the Steps won't render and hence I can't add Articles either.

What is wrong here? I am fairly new to React so I apologize if it is something silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error itself explain you can't return an array from render method of Steps component. So as a solution you can wrap your array with a div element and then return.

```
class Steps extends Component {

  render() {
    const { steps } = this.props;
    return ce('div', null, Step({ steps }));
  };

};
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Now how do I append the articles to each respective step?

Comment: Nm, figured it out. Thanks again. I was always returning an array and not actually creating a React element with those arrays.

Comment: It's hard to tell that without knowing what is the exact output you need. But I think you need to put Article component inside the element you create in the `map` function. Because that's where you can access articles array for each step with something like this `steps.map( ( { name, id, articles }, i )...`

Comment: That was exactly it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the new code for Steps component.

Comment: I am trying to render the articles but I get an error for articles.map => as unexpected token.

Comment: you have put some parenthesis in wrong places. `const Step = ({ steps }) =>
  steps.map(({ name, id, articles }, i) =>
    ce(
      "div",
      { className: "mainBoxes clearfix", key: id },
      ce("strong", { className: "titleText", key: id + "-" + i }, name),
      ce(
        "div",
        { className: "stepArticle" },
        articles.map(({ name, url }, j) => Article({ name, url }))
      )
    )
  );`

Comment: Much appreciated.